# RecyclerView show only one item

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I have a problem, I want to display a list in my second Activity but it only displays the last item and not the previous ones. I need to display all my items on Activity so.

What do I need to do to display them all?

My Activity:

```
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.home_recyclerview_pokemonname);

    mPokemonList = new ArrayList<>();

    mPokemonList.add(new MyPokemonBank("Pikachu", "Electrik"));
    mPokemonList.add(new MyPokemonBank("Dracaufeu", "Feu"));
    mPokemonList.add(new MyPokemonBank("Miaouss", "Normal"));

    mAdapter = new MyPokemonAdapter(mPokemonList);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

My Adapter:

```
public class MyPokemonAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyPokemonAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

ArrayList<MyPokemonBank> mPokemonList;

MyPokemonAdapter(ArrayList<MyPokemonBank> mPokemonList){
    this.mPokemonList = (ArrayList<MyPokemonBank>) mPokemonList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyPokemonAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pokemon_bank, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyPokemonAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.display(mPokemonList.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPokemonList.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private TextView mPokemonName;
    private TextView mPokemonType;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        mPokemonName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        mPokemonType = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
    }

    public void display(MyPokemonBank myPokemonBank) {

        this.mPokemonName.setText(MyPokemonBank.getName());
        this.mPokemonType.setText(MyPokemonBank.getType());

    }
}
}
```

Comment: check size `mPokemonList.size()` .

Comment: Can you share your view xml file?

Comment: I have posted an answer with my 2 xml

Answer (score 4):

As @Mehul Kabaria said, the problem lies in the layout of your item views. The root view in `pokemon_bank.xml` has the `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `match_parent`.

So actually all your items are displayed and if you scroll, you will see that they are there. But each item fills the whole screen which makes it look like only one item is displayed.

Change the width and height dimensions of the root view in `pokemon_bank.xml` to `wrap_content` or a fixed size.

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Pikachu">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|end"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Electrik">
</TextView>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Depending on whether you use a LinearLayoutManager for a vertical or horizontal list, you can set either the width **or** the height to `match_parent`.

Edit:

Also, it looks like you have an error in the binding of your model data to the item view in the RecyclerView Adapter:
This here uses static methods to get values from the class `MyPokemonBank`.

```
public void display(MyPokemonBank myPokemonBank) {

    this.mPokemonName.setText(MyPokemonBank.getName());
    this.mPokemonType.setText(MyPokemonBank.getType());

}
```

Instead, they should use the parameter (lowercase `myPokemonBank`):

```
public void display(MyPokemonBank myPokemonBank) {

    this.mPokemonName.setText(myPokemonBank.getName());
    this.mPokemonType.setText(myPokemonBank.getType());

}
```

Comment: I've used your code and I see 3 items but this is the same item on 3 :/

Comment: No change. Same problem :/

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `match_parent` height for your recycler view item view. Because One item fills the whole screen so you do not see another.

Comment: I don't use match_parent in layout_weight. I use wrap_content

Comment: @Ariakah : please check recyclerview list item xml.

Comment: I have posted an answer with my 2 xml

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your layout code and problem is in your pokemon_bank.xml. You need to change from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` to your linear layout compat like this it will work fine.

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="Pikachu">
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom|end"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Electrik">
    </TextView>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

You need to change from horizontal to vertical also into your main activity where you are setting layout manager like this `mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));`

Answer (score 0):

instead of this line :

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
```

try this one hope will work for you

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: Your code don't work. AS show me this error : error: ')' expected
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());

Comment: i forgot closing parenthesis please try now

Comment: Same problem and my 2 TextView is not in to the same line with your code

Comment: in pokemon_bank.xml file what is the root layout ?? you should use LinearLayout with horizontal orientation so it will display your textview in same linne

Comment: I've posted an answer with my 2 XML code. I've update to write "orientation="horizontal" but same problem. Only one item

Comment: set that linearlayout height to wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

That is my second activity XML:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/home_recyclerview_pokemonname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

and pokemon_bank.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="Pikachu">
</TextView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/type"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom|end"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="Electrik">
</TextView>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: What is the root layout used in pokemon_bank.xml ?

Comment: I edit my post with root layout